# Different behaviour of Socket Class in Dart and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tcp

i have two short Code Snippets which just serve for testing communication over a TCP Socket.

In Dart i have the following Code which compiles just fine and succesfully sends the Command to the esp8266 connected to my arduino:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.2.123', 80);

  String command = "<2,1,>";
  socket.write(command);

  print(socket.port);

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

  socket.close();
}
```

In Flutter the following snippet bound to a on Pressed Method does not succesfully sned the command:

```
class _MyStartScreenState extends State<MyStartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            color: Colors.orange,
            onPressed: _sendCommandToEsp,
            child: Text("On/Off"),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void _sendCommandToEsp() async{
    Socket socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.2.123', 80);
  
    String command = "<2,1,>";
    socket.write(command);
  
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  
    socket.close();
  }
  
}
```

Is there anything obvious I am not getting? I cannot figure out why this is the case. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you have forgot to [`flush`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/IOSink/flush.html) your socket. As noted in [`close`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Socket/close.html) you need to `flush` before `close` if you don't want to risk data to be lost.

Comment: I will try if this makes a difference, but why would it work when i run the dart code, but not when i run the flutter code. This is consistent and not random. In Dart it worked in 100% of the cases.

Comment: Well, the network stack is different on Android and Windows (and other OS'es). Since the Dart code are not running inside Dart VM but are using the Android OS on Android I would assume that the socket implementation might differ.

Comment: I should also note that if you are using `flush` it will return a Future you should use to await on instead of using `Future.delayed`.

Comment: yeah, i just the read the docs, awaiting the call of flush to finish is obvious. Thanks for the advice, i didnt think about the different implementations on Android, Linux and or Windows.

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for `close` on `Socket` you will find the following note:

> NOTE: Writes to the IOSink may be buffered, and may not be flushed by a call to `close()`. To flush all buffered writes, call [`flush()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/IOSink/flush.html) before calling `close()`.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Socket/close.html

The reason for your current behavior where it seems to work on different platforms can be because of the different network stack in each OS and that Flutter can have a different implementation of the `Socket` class than when you are running in Dart VM.

However, your current code are dependent on undocumented behavior so it is best to use the `flush()` method and await the returned `Future` so you are sure the data are actually sent before running `close()` which will destroy any data in the buffer which has yet to be sent.

Comment: Sadly even with awaiting the flush() method to complete, the Data does not get transferred to the Esp8266 Module. I am trying some thing right now, but this unexpectedly did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the Problem was that i used a port with a number smaller than 1024 which required root permisiion in most times. When I switched the Port to something higher, the Code began to work, but it still is seemingly random (at least i cant find a pattern), when the command gets received from the esp8266 and when it does not.

I will test this using a loop function with Delays.